# Python - Fastest way to find elements in XML documents

Tags: python, xml

I need to search ~10M smallish (5-10K) XML documents for the text contents of two tags. The tags do not always appear in the same place in the tree, nor do they always appear in the documents at all.

Just to clarify, if I had a document like this:

```
<a>
  <b>
    <c>
      hello
    </c>
    <d>
      goodbye
    </d>
  </b>
  <e>
    <c>
      howdy
    </c>
    <g>
      nope
    </g>
  </e>
</a>
<d>
  salutations
</d>
```

and I needed to pull out the text information from the c and d tags, I'd get

```
hello goodbye howdy salutations
```

I'm currently using `xml.etree.ElementTree.findall('.//c')`, but it's running pretty slowly. Is there a faster way to be finding these tags? Should I be using an XML parsing library at all?

I'm using Python 2.7, and [xml.etree.ElementTree](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html).

Comment: How slow is really slow, and how fast do you want it to go?

Comment: Are the tags as simple as your example? If they're just `<something>this is the text you want</something>` I'd recommend a regex.

Comment: @Thecheater887 Oh, it's not really slow by any means. I've gotten through about 2M documents in the last 75 minutes. I just suspected there was a faster way, and if that were the case, I wanted to speed this guy up and just know how to better handle this kind of situation in the future.

Comment: @porglezomp The tags have attributes, but that's certainly more than manageable in regex. You think that would be faster than an xml library?

Comment: @AndrewLaPrise Only the `c` and `d` tags, or all, such as `g` as well?

Comment: @Thecheater887 Only the `c` and `d` tags. I just included the `g` tag to demonstrate that there's information in the documents that I don't need.

Comment: @AndrewLaPrise I'm going to run a quick speed test, but, while I'm at it, have you tried `multithreading`?

Comment: @Thecheater887 It occurred to me to take that sort of route, but I went quick and dirty instead. So no, but I'm into it.

Comment: ((edited becuase of stupidity :P))

Comment: @AndrewLaPrise I can't get your stock doc from the OP to read properly. I might be doing something wrong, but, how are you parsing it? Is that just a file snippet?

Comment: @Thecheater887 I mean, I obviously just threw together a dummy doc for demo purposes. My docs have no new lines or whitespace (except in the text), but I think they're otherwise pretty similar? I just added the newlines and indenting so anyone reading this post wouldn't go insane and move on immediately. Not sure where the problem there is. I'm definitely looking for a generalized solution, though. Sorry the doc isn't working, I'll try to figure out what's wrong.

Comment: @AndrewLaPrise I realized that and fixed it. Are you seeking the same tags in every file, no variation?

Comment: @Thecheater887 Same two tags for every doc, but they could appear any number of times, including not at all.

Comment: @AndrewLaPrise I just tested `xml` against 2 other read/check systems, but `xml` beat them all. No `multithreading` was used. Sorry .-.

Comment: Thanks so much for checking that out, @Thecheater887. FYI, going the regex route resulted in HUGE speed boosts. I mean shocking speed boosts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the sound of the comments, you have two very specific tags.  No need to parse the entire file.

```
import re
pattern = re.compile(r'<[c|d][^>]*>(?P<text>[^<]*)</[c|d]>')
with open('filename', 'r') as f:
    for txt in pattern.finditer(f.read()):
        print(txt.group('text').strip())
```

Using a compiled regex and avoiding the full parse of an xml parser, you should see a significant speedup.

Answer (score 3):

Found some benchmarks in lxml docs (http://lxml.de/performance.html)

Tree traversal

Another important area in XML processing is iteration for tree traversal. If your algorithms can benefit from step-by-step traversal of the XML tree and especially if few elements are of interest or the target element tag name is known, the .iter() method is a good choice:

```
lxe: iter_all             (--TR T1)    1.0529 msec/pass
cET: iter_all             (--TR T1)    0.2635 msec/pass

lxe: iter_islice          (--TR T2)    0.0110 msec/pass
cET: iter_islice          (--TR T2)    0.0050 msec/pass

lxe: iter_tag             (--TR T2)    0.0079 msec/pass
cET: iter_tag             (--TR T2)    0.0112 msec/pass

lxe: iter_tag_all         (--TR T2)    0.1822 msec/pass
cET: iter_tag_all         (--TR T2)    0.5343 msec/pass
```

This translates directly into similar timings for Element.findall():

```
lxe: findall              (--TR T2)    1.7176 msec/pass
cET: findall              (--TR T2)    0.9973 msec/pass

lxe: findall              (--TR T3)    0.3967 msec/pass
cET: findall              (--TR T3)    0.2525 msec/pass

lxe: findall_tag          (--TR T2)    0.2258 msec/pass
cET: findall_tag          (--TR T2)    0.5770 msec/pass

lxe: findall_tag          (--TR T3)    0.1085 msec/pass
cET: findall_tag          (--TR T3)    0.1919 msec/pass
```

Note that all three libraries currently use the same Python implementation for .findall(), except for their native tree iterator (element.iter()). In general, lxml is very fast for iteration, but looses ground against cET when many Elements are found and need to be instantiated. So, the more selective your search is, the faster lxml will run.